# How to proceed from here in this infinite summation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n n^2}{1+n^4}$$
> I rewrote this as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(- \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n} \sqrt{2} n}{4 \left(n^{2} + \sqrt{2} n + 1\right)} + \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n} \sqrt{2} n}{4 \left(n^{2} - \sqrt{2} n + 1\right)}\right)$$ But this is not a telescopic series. How should I proceed now$?$

Also, does I need thorough knowledge of complex analysis to solve these kind of problems$?$ Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to play with the roots of unity writing
$$\frac {n^2}{n^4+1}=\frac {n^2}{(n-a)(n-b)(n-c)(n-d)}$$ where
$$a=-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\qquad b=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\qquad c=-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\qquad d=\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{a^2}{(a-b) (a-c) (a-d) (n-a)}+\frac{b^2}{(b-a) (b-c)
   (b-d) (n-b)}+$$ $$\frac{c^2}{(c-a) (c-b) (c-d)
   (n-c)}+\frac{d^2}{(d-a) (d-b) (d-c) (n-d)}$$ to face four sums looking like
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n}{n-k}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi
  \left(\frac{1-k}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{2-k}{2}\right)\right)$$

This leads to a beautiful result.